# What does it mean to set clipboard=unnamed?

Tags: visual-block

Today I was trying to copy and paste multiple lines in visual block mode and found this excellent [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIg6y.gif) on StackOverflow showing how to do it.

Below is a gif of what I was trying to accomplish:

[image]

When I tried this in my vim, it didn't work. But after I remove the `set clipboard=unnamed` from my vimrc, pasting a block worked flawlessly.

So, what the command `set clipboard=unnamed` does?

Comment: it's explained in `:help 'clipboard-unnamed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is answered at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691466/what-is-difference-between-vims-clipboard-unnamed-and-unnamedplus-settings). It controls, how the clipboard register of vim is used.

Or you could always just [`:h 'clipboard'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'clipboard')

Answer (score 1):

Visual-blocking pasting with `set clipboard=unnamed` works for me in Vim 8 but not in Neovim. I'm pretty sure the issue you're describing related to this longstanding [bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1822) in Neovim.

[Workaround from the thread](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1822#issuecomment-233152833) that worked for me (Neovim 0.3.1):

Install [nvim-miniyank](https://github.com/bfredl/nvim-miniyank) and add this to your config.

```
map p <Plug>(miniyank-autoput)
map P <Plug>(miniyank-autoPut)
```

Comment: To add to jasonszhao's answer, if you are like me and dont wish to install a plug in just to fix this little issue, just specify a register when you copy and paste and it will work. e.g. "ay
Maybe in 2030 it will be fixed.

Comment: In Nvim you need to use `:set clipboard+=unnamedplus`, from the documentation
"To ALWAYS use the clipboard for ALL operations (instead of interacting with
the '+' and/or '*' registers explicitly): >
    set clipboard+=unnamedplus

See 'clipboard' for details and options."